# Data is not displaying on php page from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Helo evry1
  i want to display data from phpmyadmin table to my php page but the problem is tht it not displaying here is my code

```
  <?php
    include('config.php');
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accord");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $rupes=$row['rs'];
    $mob=$row['mobilen'];
    $carmodel=$row['modelcar'];
    }
    ?>   
   PKR:<?php echo $rupes;?>   
   here is my code plz help
```

Comment: show us you config.php file with sample conection data....and dont use mysql extension...go for mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: phpmyadmin table? FYI: phpmyadmin is a application that is used as client to connect MySql database.

Comment: @jenny - what exactly is the error that you're getting? Are you getting a completely blank screen, or are you seeing `PKR:`, but there's no value next to it?

Answer (score 0):

There might be two problems

1) You have issue with config.php

2) Your query has some issue try putting die like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accord") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Here is config.php file  <?php
  $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
  $mysql_user = "root";
  $mysql_password = "";
  $mysql_database = "project";
  $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
  or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
  mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
?>

Answer (score 0):

You must `echo` your variables:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accord");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo $id=$row['id'];
    echo $rupes=$row['rs'];
    echo $mob=$row['mobilen'];
    echo $carmodel=$row['modelcar'];
    }
?>
```